# Style for ASP:GridView GridLines="None"

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, gridlines

I'm using ASP.NET standard GridView. How can I add CSS style to the property GridLines="None"?

Answer (score 0):

Try

Utimatly the gridview is going be converted as the table than you can do something like

But for the below you need to put the gridview control under div element.

```
div table
{
   border : 1px red;
}
```